# I need to check for duplicates by fields, and keep all records and returning a specific field as a value

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I perform the following:

```
Christopher Vestal 240 $506.00 11/23/2012 $0.91

Christopher Vestal 240 $43.10 11/23/2012 $0.91

Christopher Vestal 240 $77.60 11/23/2012 $0.91

Christopher Vestal 240 $16.00 11/23/2012 $0.91
```

I check the amounts and keep the highest amount with the fee and change the others to $0.00.

```
C Scott Gobble 444 $29.30 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM $0.00

C Scott Gobble 444 $104.00 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM $0.00

C Scott Gobble 444 $8.60 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM $0.00

C Scott Gobble 444 $506.00 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM $0.91
```

This is the final result I need to output in SQL.  How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant tables and sample data

Comment: It will be great to have sqlfiddle, actually not for ms-access I guess

Comment: Obviously it was not enough ...

Comment: which version of Access do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Access 2007, I stored your *Christopher* sample data in a table named `YourTable`:

```
full_name          some_number amount  date_field fee
Christopher Vestal         240 $506.00 11/23/2012 $0.91
Christopher Vestal         240  $43.10 11/23/2012 $0.91
Christopher Vestal         240  $77.60 11/23/2012 $0.91
Christopher Vestal         240  $16.00 11/23/2012 $0.91
```

This query produced the following result set.

```
SELECT
    y.full_name,
    y.some_number,
    y.amount,
    y.date_field,
    IIf(y.amount < DMax(
            "amount",
            "YourTable",
            "full_name ='" & y.full_name & "'"
            ), 0, y.fee
        ) AS adjusted_fee
FROM YourTable AS y;

full_name          some_number amount  date_field adjusted_fee
Christopher Vestal         240 $506.00 11/23/2012        $0.91
Christopher Vestal         240  $43.10 11/23/2012        $0.00
Christopher Vestal         240  $77.60 11/23/2012        $0.00
Christopher Vestal         240  $16.00 11/23/2012        $0.00
```

If you need to actually change the stored `fee` values, you can do it with this `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE YourTable AS y
SET y.fee = 0
WHERE
    y.amount < DMax(
            "amount",
            "YourTable",
            "full_name ='" & y.full_name & "'"
            );
```

Comment: thats what I am looking for although some reason I am getting this error SQL Status: 3748
Error code: -2147217904

Parameter [CURRENT BILLINGS] has no default value.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement try to use somthing like this:

```
 Select iif(Amount = Max(Amount), Fee, 0)
 From MyTable
```